# Footnote appears in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents

Footnotes are showing up on TOC:
Some headings (that are part of the TOC "Heading 3") in my manual are footnoted.  On some, a capital F appears at the end of the heading on the TOC.  How can this be eliminated now and avoided in the future?  Thanks.

Comment: Is this in MS Word?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the footnote paragraphs do not have outline set under Paragraph properties. They should be "Body Text" and not "Level X".